# Vb 10 shockwave flash with transparent background

Tags: vb.net, background, flash, transparent

About vb 2010 - i have an `.swf` file with black text with white background.

1. Can i remove the background from this swf animation?
2. If i put animation without background in vb 2010 and move it over image, will be the background transparent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Swf file is transparent then you can change AxShowwaveFlash's Background color to make it same as your Form's Background, you can use the code below.

```
Me.AxShockwaveFlash1.BGColor = Me.BackColor.R.ToString("X2") & Me.BackColor.G.ToString("X2") & Me.BackColor.B.ToString("X2")
```

Comment: Thanks, but the swf is with white background. How can i make the background transparent?

Comment: Here is reference for Transparent background in a SWF file
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/transparent-background-swf-file.html

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try this and will reply you later.